# Is it possible to distribute a recursive algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm

I’m unsure how to distribute a recursive program.  Right now its recursive and runs as a single program but my goal is distribute this program to other machines who only generate a subset of the data.

Here’s background on the program.  I give it a target (in this case 10) and a list of items with min/max weights and it returns the combinations of each.

So with 3 items, and

```
Low = 2, 2, 2
high = 6, 6, 6
Target = 10
```

The result is:

```
2 2 4
2 3 3
2 4 2
3 2 3
3 3 2
4 2 2
```

Here is the method that does the work:

```
void distribute (int i, int [] low, int [] high, final int rest, int [] sizes) {
    // System.out.println (i + " " + rest + " " + sizes);
    if (i == sizes.length - 1) {
        if (rest < high [i]) {
            sizes[i] = rest;
            result.add (Arrays.copyOf (sizes, sizes.length));
        }
    }
    else
        for (int c = 0;
             c <= java.lang.Math.min (high [i] - low [i], rest);
             ++c) {
            sizes [i] = c;
            distribute (i + 1, low, high, rest - c, sizes);
        }
}
```

I’m wondering if anyone has any ideas of how to distribute the output so, in the example above, if I have 3 servers each server only generates 2 unique entries instead of having to generate the entire thing.  Say, in advance I know there will be 6 results and want 2 to be distributed to each machine how can I do that.  Is it possible and if so what’s the logic?

If it helps, here's the entire program: http://pastebin.com/RikqPgKh

Comment: You didn't write what you are trying to achieve. What does the program do?

Comment: Its a bit domain specific, but the goal is to get different combinations of numbers that equal a specific number(in this case 10) while being bounded(in this case min-2 and max-6).  This output feeds to other programs.

Comment: If that's the actual problem statement, then it's not clear you can achieve any performance gain by distributing it.  What you have to do is at each level of recursion decide if you are going to spawn new threads or use the existing one(s).  You could spawn at every level but the overhead of creating and managing all those threads will swamp the actual processing you're doing.  If the _real_ problem is much more complex and involves I/O (where threads have to wait a significant amount of time) then threading with a fixed-size thread pool might improve performance.

Comment: as far as I understand this is subset sum, which is NP hard... Not that it should stop you from solving. It might be easier with constraints though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure you want to run the algorithm on several machines and then unite the results. You just have to split the execution. This should not be too hard as the parameters already limit the results.

For instance, instead of `L:[2,2,2] H:[6,6,6]` execute

```
L:[2,2,2] H:[3,6,6]
L:[4,2,2] H:[5,6,6]
L:[6,2,2] H:[6,6,6]
```