# Recursive Algorithm on Distributed Systems

Tags: algorithm, recursion, distributed-computing

Are there any generic systems/framework which allows to run recursive algorithms on distributed systems. Like hadoop can be used for batch processing , I am looking for framework which can enable to write recursive functions which can be executed on multiple systems.
I have already seen [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184599/is-it-possible-to-distribute-a-recursive-algorithm). Its just out of curiosity I am asking this.

Answer (score 2):

Fork/Join should do it. Although the Java 7 implementation is the most well known, you can also apply the same pattern to a [distributed system](http://www.tricode.nl/2011/08/distributed-fork-join/). Look [here](http://www.igvita.com/2012/02/29/work-stealing-and-recursive-partitioning-with-fork-join/) for a comparison with map-reduce.

Comment: Thanks jop, this seems interesting.